# UIImageView with cornerRadius is incorrectly cropped

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview, cornerradius

I am trying to add `cornerRadius` to `UIImageView` which is rectangle with small height (7pt). `UIImageView` is incorrectly cropped on the right side.
[image]

The strange thing is that `UIImageView` is perfectly rounded on a left but at the same time on the right side there is an extra white area. It is also strange that it sometimes works, roundness of right corner depends on `UIImageView` width. If I set width to 30% less right corner problem disappears.

What did I try:
Simply set corners via cornerRadius

```
layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height / 2
clipsToBounds = true
```

Set corners via Graphics context

```
func withRoundedCorners(radius: CGFloat, rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
    UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: radius).addClip()
    draw(in: rect)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Set corners via mask and path

```
extension UIImageView {
    func roundCornersForAspectFit(radius: CGFloat) {
        if let image = self.image {
            // calculate drawingRect
            let boundsScale = bounds.size.width / bounds.size.height
            let imageScale = image.size.width / image.size.height

            var drawingRect: CGRect = bounds

            if boundsScale > imageScale {
                drawingRect.size.width = drawingRect.size.height * imageScale
                drawingRect.origin.x = (bounds.size.width - drawingRect.size.width) / 2
            } else {
                drawingRect.size.height = drawingRect.size.width / imageScale
                drawingRect.origin.y = (bounds.size.height - drawingRect.size.height) / 2
            }
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: drawingRect, cornerRadius: radius)
            let mask = CAShapeLayer()
            mask.path = path.cgPath
            layer.mask = mask
        }
    }
}
```

played with different types of image contentMode

```
.scaleAspectFill 
or
.scaleAspectFit
or
.scaleToFill
```

And result is always the same.
Moreover if I remove image from `UIImageView` and just set `backgroundColor` to some random color to test it then round corner on a right side works perfectly.

What can it be?

Comment: Timing is everything. _When_ do you do this?

Comment: @matt I've tried inside of `override func layoutSubviews()` or after

Comment: Well, this is still not a [mcve]. Please provide _everything_ we need in order to _reproduce_ the issue (and no more than that).

Comment: Please attach interface builder ss

Answer (score 0):

you can add this extension to your project:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            let color = UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
            return color
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }
    
}
```

Then you can add this in your viewController and you can apply `.cornerRadius` to button, label, imageViews, etc

```
imageViewCountryImage.cornerRadius = 15
```